# How to show all the multidimensional array in PHP?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to print a multidimensional array in PHP but I not getting how to do it.

Here is the code:

```
foreach ($srcs as $img64) {

  // Vou agora apanhar a imagem e registar as suas caracteristicas
  $image          = file_get_contents($img64);
  $details_images = getimagesize($img64);
  $image_type     = pathinfo($img64, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

  // Vou converter para base64               
  $imgbase64[] .= array(
        "base64" => base64_encode($image),
        "image_type"   => $image_type
         );
}
```

If I `print_r()` the `$imgbase64` I got this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    [1] => Array
    [2] => Array
    [3] => Array
    [4] => Array
    [5] => Array
    [6] => Array
    [7] => Array
    [8] => Array
)
```

How can I print the values where is the array?

If you can give me any clue, will be appreciated.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
$imgbase64[] = array(
```

Instead of:

```
$imgbase64[] .= array(
```

`.=` is the concatenation operator, which will cast the array to a string that literally just says `"Array"`.

Comment: I'm surprised that didn't throw an error, honestly. I'm not sure what `$imgbase64[] .= array(` would even do

Comment: @Sam, If he had enabled error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT); it would have triggered a warning.

Answer (score 2):

You're using string concatenation where you should not:

```
$imgbase64[] .= array(
        "base64" => base64_encode($image),
        "image_type"   => $image_type
         );
```

That's why it's assigning the string value of `Array` to your elements. Remove the period so it is:

```
$imgbase64[] = array(
        "base64" => base64_encode($image),
        "image_type"   => $image_type
         );
```

Comment: +1, out of common courtesy. Your answer is as good as mine. :)

Answer (score 2):

Slightly off-topic (but a useful tip, so here it is).

If you simply want to output the data for debugging purposes, [var_dump](http://www.php.net/var_dump) is a better solution than print_r, as it'll recursively iterate over the data in question.